# How to get all fields related to a distinct value after Model.distinct()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this:

```
var PricelistSchema = new Schema({
  Category : String,
  Family: String,
  Others: String,
  Brand: String,
  Volume: Number,
  Price: Number,
  City: String
});
```

I get the `Distinct values` for `Family field` with `Model.distinct()` method of `mongoose`. But the Problem is i also need to know the corresponding Value of Category with Each Distinct Family value.

I tried doing it by `MapReduce` but i can't seem to get the right result. Can somebody help me in this, It's really important.

sample output:

```
{
  "_id": "56af4c63ad0fd9ec149694d2",
  "Category": "Rum",
  "Others": "0",
  "Family": "Old Monk",
  "Brand": "OLD MONK WHITE RUM",
  "Volume": 375,
  "Price": 220,
  "City": "Delhi"
},
{
  "_id": "56af4c63ad0fd9ec149694d3",
  "Category": "Rum",
  "Others": "0",
  "Family": "Old Monk",
  "Brand": "OLD MONK WHITE RUM",
  "Volume": 750,
  "Price": 440,
  "City": "Delhi"
}
```

I have nearly 3000 documents like these. I need to get only the distinct Family names in the db, but each family name should have the associated Category with it.

Right now i get:

```
["old Monk",
"Crimson",
"Cutty Sark",
"Dennis",
"Director's Special",
"Discovery",
"Double Blue",
"Evening Special",
"Everyday Gold",
"Frontline",
"Glider Superior",
"Golden Border",
"Golfer's Shot",
"Good Day",
"Haig Gold",
"Havaldar",
"Hero No.1",
"Impact",
"Imperial Blue",
"King Henry",
"King's Gold",
"Malbros Rich"
]
```

In the array i also need the Category with each field.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)** will be ideal for this case because you need to group the documents by the `Family` field  using the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator and create an array that holds the distinct `Category` values for each grouped document using the **[`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** accumulator operator.

The aggregation pipeline would have the following operation steps to include as the **[`aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate)** method parameter:

```
// Define the pipeline
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$Family",
            "Categories": { "$addToSet": "$Category" }
        }
    }
];

// Run the pipeline
PriceList.aggregate(pipeline)
         .exec(function (err, result){
             if (err) { /* Handle error */};
             console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
         });
```

or run the pipeline using the fluent API:

```
PriceList.aggregate()
         .group({
             "_id": "$Family",
             "Categories": { "$addToSet": "$Category" }
         })
         .exec(function (err, result){
             if (err) { /* Handle error */};
             console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
         });
```